# CURL: No response from curl_exec()

Tags: php, rest, curl

I am not getting any response from any url after deploying on my live server. Works fine on my local machine otherwise.

Here is my code:

```
    $url = 'www.google.com'; 

    $client= curl_init($url);

    curl_setopt($client, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER,1);

    $response = curl_exec($client);

    $response1 = json_decode($response,true);
```

I have tried `print_r(curl_getinfo($client, CURLINFO_HTTP_CODE));exit;`

It gives me `0` as output.

As mentioned earlier, everything seems to be working fine on my local machine. I have tried different urls on my server too but to no avail.

Please help.

Comment: Not _very_ helpful to you, but your code as provided works as expected and I get 200 from the print.

Comment: switch on error reporting on your server then and see if there's a problem. If you're using this on some kind of shared host, then maybe they have restrictions on outbound requests, or perhaps you have to configure a proxy or something. Who knows, without debugging information we can only speculate.

Comment: @ADyson Thanks. I'll get the error report.

Comment: @JonStirling I tried running `curl www.google.com` through terminal on the live server and it's working fine.  Any clue why it wouldn't work through a php file? Ive checked the error logs too, didnt get anything from there too.

Comment: @ADyson Error says `Couldn't resolve host "www.google.com'`

Comment: @RedBottle Not a PHP issue then, but a DNS one.

Comment: yep it sounds like your server is not correctly configured to be able to resolve hostnames - so either its DNS settings are wrong, or there's some kind of firewall in place which is preventing from accessing the internet (or certain parts of it). There's nothing wrong with your actual code (if there was, it probably wouldn't have worked in your local machine either). It's a config problem, not a programming problem. Speak to the administrator of the server.